# pch prefix clang error

Tags: clang, prefix, pch

I have my prefix pch file but I don't know why its giving me this error. Please help.

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/djtakeuchi/Documents/Xcode Projects/Xcode Supplied Source Code/BirthdayReminder/BirthdayReminder/user-interface/view-controllers/../../BRBirthdayEditViewController.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

prefix.pch file:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'BirthdayReminder' target in the 'BirthdayReminder' project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```